# Rails ckeditor gem js error when precompiled on Heroku production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using the `ckeditor` (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem on Rails 3.2.11 / Ruby 1.9.3.

I've been getting this JS error after I do `rake assets:precompile` on production environment (deployed to Heroku)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but I've traced the error (using Chrome's webdev tools) to a block that starts:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add("basicstyles", ...)
```

which I assume is the plugin responsible for adding the bold, italic, underline, and other such font style buttons to the toolbar.

The textarea is still showing without the CKEditor UI.

I'm using the latest version (4.0.4) from rubygems.

I have this in my `application.js`:

```
//= require 'ckeditor/init'
//= require 'ckeditor/config'
```

I have a custom config file in `app/assets/ckeditor/config.js` and have two custom plugins in `app/assets/ckeditor/plugins/`.

I've also tested it locally using `RAILS_ENV=production` and also not working.

Comment: You have the require statements in your Gemfile?

Comment: Sorry, bout that. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, it should have said, "application.js"

Answer (score 1):

I found what's causing the issue. It's an old uglifier version. Moving it from ~> 1.0.3 to >= 1.0.3 (which updated to 2.1.1) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that may help

Those `//= require` lines need to go in your `application.js` file, your `Gemfile` should just have `gem 'ckeditor'`.

also it should be :

`app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` and `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins`

rather than

`app/assets/ckeditor/config.js` and `app/assets/ckeditor/plugins`

Finally you can use

```
<%= f.input :content, :input_html => {:class => 'ckeditor', :rows => "10"}%>
```

in your views. Note that this is a SimpleForm input.

I used the [ckeditor-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) gem and everything went pretty smoothly for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I was using the `ckeditor` gem. I've also tried using the `ckeditor-rails` gem, but no luck there -- still getting the same js error.

I've since used `tinymce-rails` gem and that worked out of the box smoothly.

Comment: @Louis: Did you try it by yourself? Looks like I have the same issue and I have a plain `gem 'ckeditor'` in my gemfile, with the `//= require` line and nothing more, still in `production` I had no luck.